# Extracting all data from a list <li> tag using HTML Agility Pack in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using the HTML Agility Pack to extract data. I want to extract all list items from the source:

```html
<div id="feature-bullets" class="a-section a-spacing-medium a-spacing-top-small">

<ul class="a-unordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-mini">

<li><span class="a-list-item">
some data 1

</span></li>

<li><span class="a-list-item">
some data 2

</span></li>

<li><span class="a-list-item">
some data 3

</span></li>

<li><span class="a-list-item">
some data 4

</span></li>

</ul>
```

My code so far:

```
string source = someSource

var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(source);
```

How can I extract all the list items to get a result similar to this:

```
List value 1 is: some data 1
List value 2 is: some data 2
List value 3 is: some data 3
List value 4 is: some data 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the source that I am using: `amazon.co.uk/dp/B07VD9F419`. I am trying to extract the data in the bullet points.

Install additional NuGet package `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` to enable the `QuerySelector` feature. The query syntax is the same as in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Consider the following example.

```csharp
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```csahrp
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07VD9F419");

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(source);

        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("div#feature-bullets ul li span.a-list-item");

        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20) + Environment.NewLine + node.InnerText.Trim());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Console Output

```
--------------------
In addition to body weight, it also gives you a realistic picture of your health and fitness with 13 data points, such as body composition, muscle volume etc.
--------------------
High precision With a series of algori thms complexes and advanced bioelectric Impedance Analysis (BIA), provides accurate state dose.
--------------------
Weighs from 100g to 150kg so it can also weigh fruits and vegetables in addition to adults and children.
--------------------
Stores up to 16 profiles
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have tried this however since my source is a lot bigger, I got  over 40 results, here is the source that I am using: view-source:https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07VD9F419 I am trying to extract the data in the bullet points.

Comment: Also, is there any chance you know how to do the same but for the images instead?

Comment: @Josie get links? Just change the query. It's pure JS syntax, a lot of examples in www.